# Rocket.Chat - Start rocket chat from another application

Tags: android, rocket.chat

I want to implement Rocket. Chat in one of my application.
I am trying to figure out the following things:
1) How to start the Rocket.Chat UI from the application?
2) How to customize the Rocket.Chat UI like providing an Android theme, colour scheme?
3) How to Share files available in the application itself in the Rocket. Chat window, currently, 3 options are there **TAKE A PHOTO**, **ATTACH A FILE** and **DRAWING**?

Please share. Thanks.

Comment: I tried in a demo application and found that it's possible to start Rocket.Chat UI from any application. Just need to call Rocket.Chat APIs. You can create your own UI with theme in the chat screen. Also it's possible to share your application files to others in the chat window.  However in one of my projects I tried to integrate the Rocket.Chat, it's giving following error when I build the app : `Cannot open a library at ‘FileMapping(from=my-app-android/app/libs/core.jar, to=.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core.jar/8bd996c777fadbbb76d825eb83614401/jetified-core.jar)’
"`